# std::to_string not available in header string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, codeblocks

I am trying to use `std::to_string()`, of course with `#include <string>`, but the compiler gives me the error that it was not declared in the scope, after lots of searching I have tried the fixes of going to compiler settings and have `g++` follow... `-std=c++11`, 
downloading 4.7 patch header files for `wchar.h`, `stdio.h`, `os_defines.h`
and re downloading the latest codeblocks version.

but nothing makes it seem to work.

what settings do I need to change to make this work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s=to_string(10);
    cout <<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

update: I have re-installed codeblocks,version 13.12 tmd gcc, with gcc version 4.81(tmd-2), I have both -std=c++0 and -std=c++11 flags on in compiler settings,  in Toolchain executables i have c++ compiiler:mingw32-gcc-4.8.1.exe, and it Still does not recognize to_string();

Comment: What is your gcc version? Are you using MinGW?

Comment: Code works fine on GCC 4.8.1. Probably a problem with your version of the library.

Comment: I have g++ 4.8.1 in Cygwin and it does not have `to_string` even in C++11 mode.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are using the Code::Blocks MinGW distribution which includes GCC 4.7.1. The MinGW implementation of `libstdc++` does not support `to_string`, this is a [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015) which cannot be fixed by simply patching the header files. Upgrade to the latest Code::Blocks version with GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: I have uninstalled and installed the latest version of code blocks 13.12, the problem still continues

Comment: Whats the GCC version?

Comment: I am seeing the issue, I am not sure about code blocks but gcc -v says `Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)`